# How to add user-picker field for Jira custom plugin

Tags: jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm creating a custom plugin for Jira.
I now have start date and end date fields.
How can I add a field to select the user for which the report will be generated?

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${atlassian.plugin.key}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
  <plugin-info>
    ...
  </plugin-info>

  <report name="Creation Report" ...>
    <description ...>
    <resource ...>
    
    <property>
            <key>startDate</key>
            <name>report.issuecreation.startdate</name>
            <description>report.issuecreation.startdate.description</description>
            <type>date</type>
        </property>
        <property>
            <key>endDate</key>
            <name>report.issuecreation.enddate</name>
            <description>report.issuecreation.enddate.description</description>
            <type>date</type>
        </property>
        <property>
            <key>users</key>
            <name>report.issuecreation.users</name>
            <description>report.issuecreation.users.description</description>
            <type>select</type> # i don't know
            ???
        </property>
  </report>
</atlassian-plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this documentation: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/object-configurable-parameters/

Then you can see some examples like this:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <key>versionId</key>
        <name>common.concepts.version</name>
        <description>report.timetracking.version.description</description>
        <type>select</type>
        <values class="com.atlassian.jira.portal.VersionOptionalValuesGenerator"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <key>sortingOrder</key>
        <name>report.timetracking.sortingorder</name>
        <description>report.timetracking.sortingorder.description</description>
        <type>select</type>
        <values class="com.atlassian.jira.portal.SortingValuesGenerator"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <key>completedFilter</key>
        <name>report.timetracking.filter</name>
        <description>report.timetracking.filter.description</description>
        <type>select</type>
        <values class="com.atlassian.jira.portal.FilterValuesGenerator"/>
    </property>
</properties>
```

The type `select` is correct, but I believe you will need something called UserValuesGenerator, these generators basically extend com.atlassian.com.configurable.ValuesGenerator

So you can write your own UserValuesGenerator and use it.